Run Buefy toasts in composition API
In Buefy, based on the following link: Buefy Toasts when I want to use a toast notification, I need to use option API to fire the toast but when using the composition API (not possible to use this keyword), toasts are not firing and I got the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$buefy')
Here is a simple example of that working:
<b-button type="is-info is-light" @click="toast">Click to show</b-button>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            toast() {
                this.$buefy.toast.open('Something happened')
            }
        }
    }
</script>

and I need to toasts working on the following example, but as I mentioned it returns an error:
<b-button type="is-info is-light" @click="toast">Click to show</b-button>
<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    function toast() {
            this.$buefy.toast.open('Something happened')
    }

    return { toast }
  }
}
</script>

any help is appreciated.

please read the docs (1) (2)
npm install buefy@npm:@ntohq/buefy-next

import Buefy from 'buefy';
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css';

app.use(Buefy);

import { ToastProgrammatic as Toast } from 'buefy'
Toast.open('Toasty!')

UPD Arp 2024: Buefy is not migrated to Vue3 yet. please use Vuetify, Quasar, PrimeVue instead.

I have tried this before, I get this error: "TypeError: Toast.open is not a function"

yeah. looks like you're right. just created new project and this does not work at all. quick research gave me understanding that this package is not migrated to vue3 as most of the component are not ready yet. is there any reason why you need to use exact this package? can you replace it with Vuetify, Quasar, PrimeVue?

So that's the reason why it's not working! if I can call a function in methods from setup, the problem will be solved.
No, I am just starting to learn Vue and find Buefy interesting! If you know the best alternative please mention it.

I'm using Vuetify. I also tried Quasar but didn't found some fuctionality that vuetify has from the box.

If you need to show toast (snackbar in Vuetify, notify in Quasar) programmatically I'll recommend Quasar. but better check both framework and decide which one fits to your purposes
